# How do I increment every element in an array list by n elements?

Tags: java

I am only editing the bottom methods for this assignment. I am trying to increase every element of the list by n or "value" elements but I can't seem to figure out how. This is my approach so far.  There is a method for finding the min not shown that works as intended. I am only trying to modify the body of the second method

```
public class ArrayListLab 
{
   
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {          
      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      list.add(12);
      list.add(45);
      list.add(23);
      list.add(48);  
      list.add(11);      
      System.out.println("Original list is " + list);
      System.out.println("The smallest value is " + minimum(list));   // Expected: 11
      modifyList(list, 5);
      System.out.println("The new list is " + list); 
   }
  

   public static void modifyList(List<Integer> list, int value)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < value; i++);  
         list.get(i) += value;

   }
```

Comment: The output would print the list and then just add 5 to each number in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update your `for` loop to go from 0 to the length of `list` (`for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)`) instead of go from 1 to `value` (`for(int i = 0; i < value; i++)`). You also need to remove the `;` at the end of `for` statement so the Java program will take the list update code below instead of looping through an empty block of code.

Regarding how to update an `ArrayList` object, you can use the `set`function for that (`list.set(i, list.get(i) + value)`)

```
public static void modifyList(List<Integer> list, int value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
        list.set(i, list.get(i) + value);

}
```

Update: To rotate the ArrayList like you mention, you can remove and return the first element in the list using the function `remove(0)` and the just add it to end of the list using the `add` function like you did in the `main` function

```
public static void rotateList(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        list.add(list.remove(0));
}
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey Ok I've updated the code with the function  for rotating n values in the list

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the list.

```
    public static void modifyList(List<Integer> list, int value)
           {
              for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){  
                 list.set(i, list.get(i) + value);
              }
        
           }
```

Comment: "cannot find symbol i

Comment: and cannot find symbol length

Answer (score 1):

So you have a couple of problems, first in the method `modifyList()` the parameter `List<Integer>` should actually be `ArrayList<Integer>`. Furthermore, your *for loop* must have a `{` instead of `;` at the end of the line.

An easier way to loop through `ArrayLists` is

```java
for(Integer i : list) {list.set(i, i+value); }
```

Also, the `minimum(list)` is undefined.

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp for help on arraylists

Comment: to remove and then add its `int holdValue = list.get(i); list.remove(i);list.add(holdValue); `

Comment: Yup just right, for better optimization you can do `rotate = rotate % list.size()` this will handle all the higher numbers like 100 and so. when we rotate a list whose size is 5 it's the same as rotating 100 times. by doing this `rotate = rotate % list.size()` you are saving a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there are 2 errors

1. Logical
2. Syntax

Syntax `for(int i = 0; i < value; i++);`   there's a `;` and cause of that your variable `i` wont get recognized or say it would be out of scope.

Logical:
When you did `list.get(i)` all it does is, Gives you the value associated with that index.
You can do like `int sum = list.get(i) + value`  what this will do it get the `value` from the list at index `i` and then add the number `5` to it.
 So now your sum holds `value from index i + 5` which you wanted.

Now all you gotta do it `set` the index at `i` to the `sum` we calculated.
When we do `list.set(i, sum)` it overwrites the value at that `index` with our sum.

```
public static void modifyList(ArrayList<Integer> list, int value)
       {
          for(int i = 0 ; i < value ;i++) {
           int sum = list.get(i) + value;
            list.set(i,sum);  
          }
       }
```